# Running ROS and its gui tools through a docker image

Tags: docker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am experimenting creating a standard environment for my students to run ROS without having to install anything, because that always goes wrong somehow. In other posts I have questions about VNC and X. This question is similar:
Is it possible, and how, to create a docker image based on Ubuntu and ROS that when launched will allow ROS development and testing to happen including running tools like Gazebo, RViz, RQT etc etc. Have you done it? Have you seen it written up? I am successful at this point to get everything to work in the container, EXCEPT trying to run say RQT which fails with "QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display" and many other errors. If desired I will attach my Dockerfile.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313786/running-ros-and-its-gui-tools-through-a-docker-image/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2019-01-25

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(Strictly speaking, this is not an answer, but I needed more characters than the comment allowed)

For students, I would take a look at [Singularity](https://www.sylabs.io/).

It uses the same techniques, but doesn't require super user rights, mounts `$HOME` by default, runs everything as the `$USER` that started the container, and allows access to devices *and* GPUs by default.

There isn't even any special configuration needed with Singularity containers to be able to use GUIs.

And it allows you to import/run/exec Docker images, so you can start from `osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full` for instance.

---

Edit: as an answer to your original question: yes, it's certainly possible to run GUI applications from inside Docker containers.  Some of the approaches are documented over at [wiki/docker](http://wiki.ros.org/docker). An alternative can be seen at [osrf/car_demo](https://github.com/osrf/car_demo).

---

Edit2: here's a three line example to get RViz running from inside a Singularity "shell" (essentially equivalent to a `docker run -it ..`):

```
# needed once: converts Docker image into Singularity image on your local system
singularity pull --name ros-kinetic-desktop-full.simg docker://osrf/ros:kinetic-desktop-full

# in terminal 1: roscore
singularity exec -p ./ros-kinetic-desktop-full.simg bash -c 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash; roscore'

# in terminal 2: rviz

# if you have nvidia hw and the proprietary driver installed:
singularity exec --nv -p ./ros-kinetic-desktop-full.simg bash -c 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash; rviz'

# if you have a built-in Intel GPU or are using nouveau
singularity exec -p ./ros-kinetic-desktop-full.simg bash -c 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash; rviz'
```

Note: I'm using Singularity 2.5.2 commands here. Singularity 2.6 (and 3.0) will have changed the way it interacts with NVidia hw.

The `-p` is to make sure all child processes in the container are terminated when the container terminates.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2019-01-28**:
+1 for the three line Singularity example. When you have the time, a post or wiki about using ROS with singularity would be cool. It seems v3.0 has changed up some things, but searching the docs, I didn't see anything much on nvidia/gpu.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-29**:
I've been meaning to, but as always, time and other obligations have prevented me from doing that so far.

re: 3.0 changes: yes, it's a complete rewrite (in golang) and it's changed quite a few things.

re: gpu: there is nothing special to do, as Singularity allows access to `/dev` by default. What *is* needed is to "install" the required drivers in the image. But as you don't want to do that, a similar trick to what `nvidia-docker(2)` did/does is used: mount those into the container. The specifics of that have changed between 2.x and 3.x, but in principle things "just work".

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2019-01-29**:
@gvdhoorn thanks for the example. And yes of course I know docker. That's what I've been using (among other things) to get this to work. It seems that Singularity only works natively on unix and needs a VM to run on Mac, which is my environment. Will it perform ok then? I worry about docker + vm

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-29**:\

> And yes of course I know docker.

You wrote:

> [..] without a handle on what the thing does, which keeps me from just typing in the commands!

Which made me ask myself (and you) whether you (truely) know what Docker does when you give it a command. I merely found it a curious thing to say.

> It seems that Singularity only works natively on unix and needs a VM to run on Mac, which is my environment. Will it perform ok then? I worry about docker + vm

Singularity right now apparently only runs natively under Linux, but can be made to run on OSX. See [sylabs/singularity#109](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/issues/109).

I've not done that myself and it's probably not something I'd recommend doing in a production environment/class/uni course where you depend on your tools being stable.

re: vm: Singularity is not magic, so will suffer in a VM as any other tool would. How much of an impact there is of course depends on the types of workloads.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2019-01-29**:
It was a curious answer, and yet it was true. I would say my level of docker expertise is intermediate not expert. But really without context the singularity web site doesnt explain what it does. I couldnt even tell for sure if it was software I installed or it was a cloud service.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-05**:
Seems there is some movement on the OSX + Singularity front: [sylabs/singularity#2675](https://github.com/sylabs/singularity/pull/2675) just got merged.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be interested in a small python tool from OSRF named Rocker

> A tool to run docker containers with overlays and convenient options for things like GUIs etc.

https://github.com/osrf/rocker

It's basically helpful CLI around Docker that enables display/audio forwarding and hardware acceleration to container to simplify using ROS GUIs with Docker. I'm sure @tfoote would appreciate any feedback should you try out the project.

---

Edit: Just to throw it out there, you may also want to checkout web based environments for developing ROS, e.g:

- ROS Development Studio

  - http://www.theconstructsim.com
  - https://discourse.ros.org/t/rosject-share-your-project-through-a-shareable-link/5920
- AWS RoboMaker

  - https://aws.amazon.com/robomaker
  - https://discourse.ros.org/t/check-out-aws-robomaker/6947

However, web based environments may pose their own challenges if your intent is to also interact with physical robots locally in a lab/class room. Still I imagine a combination of the theses methods would do nicely. E.g RDS/AWS for homework and Docker/Singularity for in lab sessions.

---

Originally posted by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) with karma: 1094 on 2019-01-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-28**:
@pitosalas: `rocker` is what is used in `osrf/car_demo` I linked to in my answer.

I still feel Singularity makes more sense in an environment with students, if only for the fact that it doesn't need super user privileges.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2019-01-28**:
@gvdhoorn I looked at singularity's web site and admit I don't understand how to use it. I kind of understand what they say it does but I am lost on where to start. I did read the doc and the quick start but without a handle on what the thing does, which keeps me from just typing in the commands!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-28**:
You'll want to check the [user manual](https://www.sylabs.io/guides/2.6/user-guide/index.html). Especially the quick start and introduction sections.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-28**:\

> I did read the doc and the quick start but without a handle on what the thing does, which keeps me from just typing in the commands!

do you know what Docker does?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the latest ros image (e.g., ros:melodic) and install the ROS desktop version ([my simple custom Dockerfile](https://github.com/dratasich/docker/tree/master/ros-gui) for the GUI tools). Then I start all GUI tools with [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker).

Works like a charm:

```
$ x11docker --hostnet ros:gui rviz
$ x11docker --hostnet ros:gui rqt_graph
```

I'm using `--hostnet` (cf. `--network=host`) for simplicity. `ros:gui` is the tag of my custom Docker image.

---

Originally posted by [dratasich](https://answers.ros.org/users/40204/dratasich/) with karma: 11 on 2019-02-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-01-18**:
I am on Mac so x11docker is not available to me... :(

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For those, who are still looking for an easy ROS usage: https://hub.docker.com/r/johannhaselberger/coros

This will allow you to use all ROS GUI tools within your browser - on mac, linux and even windows.

---

Originally posted by [Johann.Haselberger](https://answers.ros.org/users/44674/johann.haselberger/) with karma: 21 on 2020-02-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-03-04**:
@Johann.Haselberger thanks. I am not sure how I launch your docker container from there. Can you give me the sequence? Thanks.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-04-23**:
@johann.haselberger can I ask you a question about #coros?

**Comment by [Johann.Haselberger](https://answers.ros.org/users/44674/johann.haselberger/) on 2020-04-24**:
@pitosalas: Yes feel free to ask, you could also create an issue on the GitHub project.

Also on docker hub / GitHub there is a small documentation. The section Start the service is exactly what you are looking for.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2020-04-25**:
@johann.Haselberger thanks. I tried it on a cloud host and it worked and now I am trying it locally on my Mac and it seems to work nicely too. Question: it says FROM ros:melodic but where is that Dockerfile so I can see what it is doing?