# Does Docker provide a full Ubuntu GUI development environment like VirtualBox for ROS Noetic

Tags: docker, ros-noetic

I can't seem to find a proper answer to this question by reading through Docker documentation.

If Docker is touted as a lighter alternative to VMs installed via tools like VirtualBox, does it provide the full Ubuntu GUI development environment for ROS Noetic (for example)?

There's an [older question on this](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/90228/running-ros-and-its-gui-tools-through-a-docker-image), but the answers given don't make it seem like Docker provides a GUI dev environment natively. But rather through a bunch of different add-ons.

I'm not an advanced ROS developer, so I don't want the hassle of not having the "vanilla" ROS dev environment of a "vanilla" Ubuntu OS with full GUI.

If someone can confirm that Docker can't support GUI dev environment natively, then I'd rather stick to using VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No GUI environment exists that I know of. Assuming your on a Linux based system you can just mount your x11 directory and set your display variable.

For example:

First step enter the console command

```
xhost +
```

Start a basic ubuntu docker container with the x11 volume mounted and the env variable set.

```
docker run -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --env DISPLAY=${DISPLAY} ubuntu bash
```

Now in the container install xapps (since base image has no gui based tools)

```
apt update && apt install -y x11-apps
```

and test using

```
xeyes
```

You can even do this with GPU support using the Nvidia container toolkit.  For Mac and Windows this I believe you just use XQuartz or VcXsrv Windows X Server

Typically I prefer using docker compose for settings these variables and launching/building my containers.